# TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'axes'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, seq2seq, attention-model

I want to use attention mechanism with the code bellow :

```
attention = Dot([decoder_outputs, encoder_outputs], axes=[2, 1])
attention = Activation('softmax')(attention)

context = Dot([attention, encoder_outputs], axes=[2,1])
decoder_combined_context = concatenate([context, decoder_outputs])
```

But i have this error message and i don't know how to fix it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    attention = Dot([decoder_outputs, encoder_outputs], axes=[2, 1])

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'axes'
```

I'm using keras version 2.3.1 with tensorflow version 2.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to [`Dot`](https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/dot/) *is* called `axes`:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dot(axes, normalize=False, **kwargs)
```

So you need to decide what value you want to pass for `axes`: either `[decoder_outputs, encoder_outputs]` or `[2, 1]`.

Comment: i used this but i still have an issue with the second it gives me an error for the axes, is it correct to put axes=[2,1] for both of them ?  
`attention = Dot(axes=[2,1])` 
`attention = attention([decoder_outputs, encoder_outputs])` 
`attention = Activation('softmax')(attention) `

Answer (score 3):

You are not calling the layer correctly, it should be like this:

```
attention = Dot(axes=[2, 1])([decoder_outputs, encoder_outputs])
```

Your second call to `Dot` has the same issue, it follows the same pattern

Comment: i used this but for the second it gives me an error for the axes, is it correct to put axes=[2,1] for both of them ?
`attention = Dot(axes=[2,1])
attention = attention([decoder_outputs, encoder_outputs])
attention = Activation('softmax')(attention)`

Comment: @YounesSaadna You need to be specific about the error for the axes

Comment: the error is 
`ValueError: Dimension incompatibility None != 256. Layer shapes: (None, None), (None, 256)`
i don't know why the sahpe of attention is (None,None) ?